# How to record screen to video on iPhone with openGL (view preview layer) and UIkit elements?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, gpu, movie, gpuimage

I have searched everywhere and tried mixing and matching different bits of code but I haven't found anything that works or anyone with the same question.

Basically I want to be able to create video demos of iPhone apps that include standard UIKit elements and also the image coming from the camera (video preview layer).  I don't want to use airPlay or iOS simulator to project onto the desktop then capture because I want to be able to make videos outside in public.  I have successfully been able to video capture the screen with this [code](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673)  but with the video preview layer being blank.  I read that its because its using openGL and what I'm capturing is from the CPU, not the GPU.  I have successfully used GPUImage from Brad Larson to capture the video preview layer but it doesn't capture the rest of the UIView.  I have seen code that combines both and converts to an image but I'm not sure if that would be too slow for realtime video capture.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know anything about the iPhone, but if you have control over the OpenGL code, you can fetch the contents with glReadPixels (slow !), or render to a texture. Then mix with the CPU-side screenshot.

Comment: Thanx for the tip.  I've checked out rendering to a texture.  I'm not sure where to put the initialisation code and the capturing code though.  The UIView capture function that I'm currently using is all encapsulated within a separate class to the camera processing class.  Should I be moving that functionality within the CaptureOutput callback of my camera processing class?  I was hoping to keep it independent so I can plug it into any app.  The fact that there is no code anywhere on the net that can video cap CPU+GPU together makes me think this may not be possible, or just too slow

Comment: As I said, I don't know anything about these iPhone classes. RenderToTexture : you need a callback at the very beginning to setup the texture, a callback just before the render to set the target framebuffer, and a callback after the render to fetch the texture. glReadPixels : you just need a callback after the render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the cleanest solution, but it will work nonetheless: did you consider jailbreaking? I hope Apple does sue me for this one but if you really want to record your screen then simply install a screen recorder. Enough options can be found: http://www.google.be/search?q=iphone+jailbreak+record+screen

And if you don't like it: recover your phone for a previous backup.

(for the record: I'm against jailbreaking and posting this from a productivity point of view)